# R set up dataframe for Sankey diagram - need transform data with permutations and new indexes

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how I can go from a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Customer_Id <-    c(200, 200, 201, 201, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200)
Invoice_Number <- c(100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103)
Product <- c("Cookie", "Sandwich", "Bagel", "Sandwich", "Toast", "Cigarette", "Coffee", "Milk", "Sugar", "Cream", "Juice")   
Visit_Number <- c("First Visit", "First Visit", "First Visit", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Most Recent Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "Most Recent Visit")   

df <- data.frame(Customer_Id, Invoice_Number, Product, Visit_Number)
```

[image]

To a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Customer_Id <-    c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
                    200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
                    200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200)
Pathway <-        c(201, 201, 202, 202, 203, 203, 204, 204, 
                    205, 205, 206, 206, 207, 207, 208, 208, 209, 209, 
                    210, 210, 211, 211, 212, 212, 213, 213, 214, 214, 215, 215)
Invoice_Number <- c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 
                    111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 
                    121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130)
Product <- c("Cookie", "Coffee", "Cookie", "Milk", "Cookie", "Sugar", "Cookie", "Cream", "Cookie", "Juice", "Sandwich", "Coffee", "Sandwich", "Milk", "Sandwich", "Sugar", "Sandwich", "Cream", "Sandwich", "Juice", 
             "Bagel", "Coffee", "Bagel", "Milk", "Bagel", "Sugar", "Bagel", "Cream", "Bagel", "Juice")
Visit_Number <- c("First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit", "First Visit", "Most Recent Visit")

df2 <- data.frame(Customer_Id, Pathway, Invoice_Number, Product, Visit_Number)
```

[image]

Here is what is going on. I'm trying to look at customer invoices and understand how customers switch from buying one thing at their first visit to buying a different thing at their most recent visit. I would love to create a Sankey diagram from this. But the first task is to coerce the data to look a certain way so I can use the `ggalluvial` package.

The problem is, a customer might have three items (in our case, 'Cookie', 'Sandwich', and 'Bagel' as part of their basket on their first visit and five different items: 'Coffee', 'Milk', 'Sugar', 'Cream', 'Juice' one their most recent visit.

After we get rid of the "Other" category and only look at First Visit vs Most Recent Visit, there are 15 permutations of the First Visit vs the Most Recent Visit item switch. This customer switched from Cookies to Coffee, and also switched from Cookie to Milk and Cookie to Sugar and Cookie to Cream.

And then what I need is for each permutation to have its own Customer ID and also for each permutation to have its own unique pair of invoice numbers, that don't appear anywhere else.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do. In your source data customer 200 has "Cookie" and "Sandwich" under "First Visit". "Bagel" is for customer 201. You say *"customer might have three items (in our case, 'Cookie', 'Sandwich', and 'Bagel' as part of their basket on their first visit [...]"*. Why do purchases of customers with id 200 and 201 get lumped together?

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Maybe in the second dataframe the name of the column as 'Customer_Id' isn't really appropriate anymore and I should call it Pathway. In the second dataframe, the important thing is that the Customer_Id joins together one of the stories from First Invoice to Most Recent Invoice, that had been part of the same customer. In the example I gave, everything was part of Customer 200. Maybe a less confusing solution would be to leave the Customer_Id as 200 for that patient but also create another column, called Pathway, or something, that has these 15 different groups

Comment: Hi @hachiko. Not sure your response is very helpful here; I'm reading a lot of "maybe"s. How are we supposed to help if you're not even sure what you're trying to do? Can you please *edit* your post and include relevant clarifications in the main post (comments are transient).

Comment: @MauritsEvers I edited the post based on the feedback. It should be much more clear now, since the confusion was just about using the same name in df2 for something that was different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is that we only have to worry about the Product column, all else can be filled in by simple repetition at the end. The Product combinations can be obtained in a column with the desired order via `expand.grid` and some further manipulation.

```r
library(dplyr)

expand.grid(filter(df, Visit_Number == "First Visit")$Product,
            filter(df, Visit_Number == "Most Recent Visit")$Product) %>%
  t() %>%
  c() %>%
  data.frame(Product = .) %>%
  mutate(Invoice_Number = row_number() + 100,
         Pathway = ceiling(row_number() / 2) + 200,
         Visit_Number = rep(c("First Visit", "Most Recent Visit"), times = nrow(.) / 2)) %>%
  select(Pathway, Invoice_Number, Product, Visit_Number)

#    Pathway Invoice_Number  Product      Visit_Number
# 1      201            101   Cookie       First Visit
# 2      201            102   Coffee Most Recent Visit
# 3      202            103 Sandwich       First Visit
# 4      202            104   Coffee Most Recent Visit
# 5      203            105    Bagel       First Visit
# 6      203            106   Coffee Most Recent Visit
# 7      204            107   Cookie       First Visit
# 8      204            108     Milk Most Recent Visit
# 9      205            109 Sandwich       First Visit
# 10     205            110     Milk Most Recent Visit
# 11     206            111    Bagel       First Visit
# 12     206            112     Milk Most Recent Visit
# 13     207            113   Cookie       First Visit
# 14     207            114    Sugar Most Recent Visit
# 15     208            115 Sandwich       First Visit
# 16     208            116    Sugar Most Recent Visit
# 17     209            117    Bagel       First Visit
# 18     209            118    Sugar Most Recent Visit
# 19     210            119   Cookie       First Visit
# 20     210            120    Cream Most Recent Visit
# 21     211            121 Sandwich       First Visit
# 22     211            122    Cream Most Recent Visit
# 23     212            123    Bagel       First Visit
# 24     212            124    Cream Most Recent Visit
# 25     213            125   Cookie       First Visit
# 26     213            126    Juice Most Recent Visit
# 27     214            127 Sandwich       First Visit
# 28     214            128    Juice Most Recent Visit
# 29     215            129    Bagel       First Visit
# 30     215            130    Juice Most Recent Visit
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, thanks for the quick response. As it turns out, my dataframe has way too many customer_ids and the customers buy way too many different kinds of products, and the number of permutations across first and most recent invoice is gigantic, and I can't easily feed the result into a alluvial plot anyway!

Comment: Fair enough haha, I learned quite a bit writing this so it was all worth it.